# dart paper-scaffold background-color=#526E9C for header. Where to change?

Tags: css, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I have read the answers to the other [very] related questions, but I thought I would pose it again since polymer updates might have been made.

I can change all the colors in [dart] paper-scaffold (core-scaffold) - the menu and toolbar, but I cannot change the color of the header across the top. It is always background-color=#526E9C. The only way I can do it is change the core-toolbar style in the generated (using pub build) index.html. And this **one line change** sets the color across the **whole header** across the browser window (which is what I want). So I can get by.

When I do style:

```
core-toolbar{
background-color: #7A418D;
color: #FFF;
}
```

it only changes the color above the drawer, and not across the whole top. It's very mysterious why it just does that bit!

I have tried shadow-shim, core-scaffold::shadowdom.. etc. I have tried changing the /src/ core-scaffold.html - and more, where this pervasive value #526E9C appears.

In my website (sekpa.org) it shows this blue (#526E9C) half.

Is it just a bug? If it is, I'd be very happy in that knowledge!
Thanks
 Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `core-header-panel`s inside a `paper-scaffold`.

Each `core-header-panel` contains one `core-toolbar`.

The left collapsible `core-header-panel` as well as its inner `core-toolbar` are sitting in the normal Light DOM, and that's why you can change its color by specifying the css like that.

However, the right `core-header-panel` and `core-toolbar` are inside `paper-scaffold`'s Shadow DOM. In order to change the color of this `core-toolbar`, you need to do something like -

```
paper-scaffold::shadow core-toolbar {
  background: #7A418D;
  color: #fff;
}
```

For more info, please refer to this [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html).

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks. I'd been doing "core-scaffold:shadow...".   Cheers, Steve

Comment: Hi @Lymp, if you think my answer is helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I'm a newbie. Done. Didn't know I had to do that. Thanks. Steve